# Get JSON Object from URL using Express

Tags: json, reactjs, express

In the express users.js file:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  fetch('https://www.somwhere.com/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
});

module.exports = router;
```

In my App.js file for my React App I use

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/users')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(users => this.setState({ users }));
    }
```

Right now it throws a 500 error and its not catching the error

Can I get some help fixing this

Comment: Use `fetch` with external URL in your `route` then return response with `res.json`

Comment: thanks for the help, I have edited my code above with what I am running into right now.

Comment: Use `fetch('/localhost:3000/')` in your `App.js` not `fetch('/users')`

Comment: **zerosand1s:** I don't think so, I think he uses `app.use('/users', userRouter)`, that's why he doesn't use `router.get('/users')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `axios` in your FrontEnd("React") and BackEnd("Express"). **This code below only an example code** that you can follow:

**Backend:** Express Server Using `axios`

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors( { origin: '*'}));

const END_POINT = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

app.get('/users', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(END_POINT);
    res.status(200).send(data);
  } catch(ex) {
    res.status(500).send(ex.data);
  }
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is up');
});
```

**The code above only an example** if you want to using `axios` in your backend.

**Updated:** Using `fetch`

If you still want to using `fetch`, then you can use code below :

```js
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    const json = await result.json();
    res.status(200).send(json);
  } catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex);
    res.status(500).send(ex.message);
  }
})

module.exports = router;
```

**FrontEnd:** React Using `axios`

```js
async componentDidMount() {
  try {
    // change the endpoint with yours
    const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/users');
    console.log(data);
    // do some stuff here: set state or some stuff you want
  } catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex);
  }
}
```

**Dont Forget** to install and import `axios` in your React App.

**Updated:** If you still want to using `fetch` in your React App, than you can use this code below:

```js
async componentDidMount() {
  try {
    // change the endpoint with yours
    const result = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/users');
    const json = await result.json();
    console.log(json);
    // do some stuff here: set state or some stuff you want
  } catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex);
  }
}
```

I hope it's can help you .